# eclipse use available space line w

Tags: java, eclipse, format, space

in our company we recently changed the used line width from like 80 to 150.
Now it is quite annoying that all code is - of course - wrapped after 100 characters, as this was the previous setting.

We use save actions to run the format settings and it all works wonderful in the one direction: wrap too large lines.

But what I need now: UNWRAP me all lines as I now got enough space available, USE it. Is there a possibility to do that in form of a format setting? I couldn't find any

I now got this line (extremly) wrapped as there were not enough space:

```
    final List<SomeSuperDuperType> 
mySuperDuperListOfSuperDuperTypes = 
CrazyUtils.gimmeSomeCrazyStuffAsList(
parameter1, parameter2);
```

Now, with more space available, this code is still correctly formatted as it doesn't exceed the limit. Though I want to actually USE that extra space and make the line now like this (`length=133`):

```
final List<SomeSuperDuperType> mySuperDuperListOfSuperDuperTypes = CrazyUtils.gimmeSomeCrazyStuffAsList(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Comment: are you using the save actions to modify the edited lines or all the file ?
Formatting the code should unwrap it automatically.

Comment: All the file.
If you have checked the flag "Never join already wrapped lines" it won't do that. I also was used to that behavior and wondered, why no unwrapping was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Eclipse, go to Window>Preferences>Java>Code Style>Formatter, edit the active profile, and you'll find what you're looking for under the tab Line Wrapping.

Then, select all your code (CTRL+A) and use CTRL+Shift+F to format the text using these new setttings.

Comment: You are right.

The specific flag is the "[] Never join already wrapped lines" which is checked here in my company. Taking this out works. I seemed to be blind not finding this... Sometimes you just need a fresh, second look :)

Comment: Yeah, it happens to me all the time, I just don't see things that are right in front of me! Glad I could help.